# How to configure istanbul coverage report to exclude certain sources?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm developing a nodeJS + angular stacked application. To generate the code coverage reports for the backend I use istanbul and mocha. However, the coverage reports show incorrect figures.

If I run `istanbul cover _mocha --print detail /path/to/tests*` I get full coverage (but only on the file that is requires by the test spec). On the other hand if I run `istanbul cover _mocha --print detail --include-all-sources /path/to/tests*` istanbul also checks the test coverage for the frontend code (angular, which I test with karma/jasmine separately).

How do I run istanbul so it includes only the backend source files?

Answer (score 2):

According to istanbul help cover output

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/istanbul help cover

Usage: istanbul cover [<options>] <executable-js-file-or-command> [--<arguments-to-jsfile>]

Options are:

  --config <path-to-config>
          the configuration file to use, defaults to .istanbul.yml

  --root <path>
          the root path to look for files to instrument, defaults to .

  -x <exclude-pattern> [-x <exclude-pattern>]
          one or more glob patterns e.g. "**/vendor/**"

  -i <include-pattern> [-i <include-pattern>]
          one or more glob patterns e.g. "**/*.js"

  --[no-]default-excludes
          apply default excludes [ **/node_modules/**, **/test/**,
          **/tests/** ], defaults to true

  --hook-run-in-context
          hook vm.runInThisContext in addition to require (supports
          RequireJS), defaults to false

  --post-require-hook <file> | <module>
          JS module that exports a function for post-require processing

  --report <format> [--report <format>]
          report format, defaults to lcov (= lcov.info + HTML)

  --dir <report-dir>
          report directory, defaults to ./coverage

  --print <type>
          type of report to print to console, one of summary (default),
          detail, both or none

  --verbose, -v
          verbose mode

  --[no-]preserve-comments
          remove / preserve comments in the output, defaults to false

  --include-all-sources
          instrument all unused sources after running tests, defaults to
          false

  --[no-]include-pid
          include PID in output coverage filename
```

You should use the -X to exclude some files from coverage reporting. i.e:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha test -X dist/index.js
```

Will execute the test, and ignore the dist/index.js file on coverage reporting

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your backend code and your frontend code in separate directories? For example `/test/api` and `/test/dashboard` or whatever. If you keep your code separate, you can tell istanbul to report on each at a time like so:

`istanbul cover _mocha test/api/**/*.js`

Makes sense? Would that work for you at all?

Let me know.

Comment: The structure of my project is more like 
<code>
    server/*
    public/js* (angular)
    test/mocha/* (backend tests)
    test/jasmine/* (angular tests)
</code>

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar situation and hence thought it's worth sharing if it could help someone though its an old post. **Istanbul** takes the current directory **(.)** as a coverage directory while running the command. In order to include just a specific directory to coverage scope use `"--root /dir/"` option. This would generate coverage report only for the files in that directory.